# Find Zoom URL to join call from text

Tags: python, regex, url

I am trying to find the join link to a Zoom call from any chunk of text. How can I use regex to appropriately only identify the zoom URL to join the call and not any other URLs such as the one for international numbers or to different websites?

What I have now is a very dumb function that simply returns the first URL it finds in a chunk of text. This clearly doesn't work if the zoom link isn't the first link in the text.

If this were the text:

> Check out this link that isn't a zoom link: https://www.google.com/
>
> You are invited to a scheduled Zoom meeting.
>
> Topic: A Zoom Meeting Room
>
> Join from PC, Mac, Linux, iOS or Android: https://zoom.us/j/room_number
> Or Telephone：###-###-####
> Meeting ID: ### ### ####
> International numbers available: https://zoom.us/u/dghsfhhg

I only want to return https://zoom.us/j/room_number. I should be able to find personal links, scheduled meetings, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex that will accomplish this is based on your example is `https://zoom.us/j/.+?\b`. Depending on the range of valid Zoom links this may need to be updated.

You can use this in Python like so:

```
import re

text = "I only want to return https://zoom.us/j/room_number."
match = re.search("https://zoom.us/j/.+?\b", text)

if match is not None:
    print(match.group(0))
```

You can see how this regex works at https://regex101.com/r/D6wOum/3.

Comment: If I want it to find this URL `https://us02web.zoom.us/...` as well, how do I use regex to search for the optional "us02web."? The us02web. part of the URL could be substituted for any organization which has a zoom account. How would I be able to find `https://yale.zoom.us/...` or `https://mit.zoom.us/...`?

Comment: Would it be something like this? `[a-z|0-9|.]?`

Comment: You can try `https://(.*\.)?zoom.us/[a-z]/.+?\b` but as you can see here (https://regex101.com/r/D6wOum/4) this also picks up the "international number" link. So to really be accurate you're going to need to know exactly what the patterns are that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex:

```
https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S\S
```

This regex can surely be improved, but what I did works

See how it works (it works for any url, not only zoom):

https://regex101.com/r/t5YWO2/1